# Does pg_archivecleanup command effect on replication slot?

Tags: postgresql, database-administration, database-replication, postgresql-9.5

As per replication slot definition, it is a feature in PostgreSQL that ensure that the master server will retain the WAL logs that are needed by the replicas even when they are disconnected from server.

Is there any effect if I run pg_archivecleanup command every 15th day of month to free my storage. Does it has any effect on replication slot, since it is tracing WAL file which is required by standby server?

Because I run pg_archivecleanup  removing WAL file from last checkpoint but I am not sure whether it is removing WAl file that is required for other replica.

If not removing then how it is actually tracing it?

I am looking for explanation from experts.

Comment: Why have an archive at all?  Since you want to clean it so aggressively, just turn archiving off and let the slots do their thing.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `pg_archivecleanup`, PostgreSQL will delete all WAL segments that  are older than the WAL segment you specify as argument.  This will **ignore replication slots**, you you may end up removing WAL segments that may still be needed by standby servers to catch up (if they do that using `restore_command`).

Note that this normally not a problem, because `pg_archivecleanup` deletes WAL segments *from the archive*, while replication slots deal with WAL segments *on the primary server* (in the `pg_wal` directory), which are not affected by `pg_archivecleanup`. Now since the standby consumes WAL directly from the primary (as specified in `primary_conninfo`), it does not have to rely on the WAL archives.